# Como exibir, em formato treeview, apenas as pastas e subpastas, e o conteúdo de ambas, que estão no desktop?

Tags: c#, sistema-de-arquivos, treeview

Boas pessoal, gostaria de uma ajuda por obséquio 
Fiz um file explorer que tem como objetivo, mapear todas as pastas,subpastas e os arquivos dessas pastas e subpastas de acordo com a letra que for selecionada.
O problema é que, ao selecionar qualquer letra, o programa mostra as pastas que começam pela letra selecionada e  sempre mostra quaisquer arquivos que não estejam dentro de uma pasta, no desktop. 
    O resultado fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A função que usei para mostrar as pastas e subpastas e os arquivos de ambas,  é essa

```
        var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
        var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories(letra))
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory, letra));

        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
        return directoryNode;
```

Como posso fazer para que ao selecionar a letra, apareça apenas as pastas,subpastas e os arquivos de ambas ?
Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: O que parece que falta, é no código de inserir os ficheiros, apenas adicionar à árvore, os ficheiros que começam pela letra. Tem de colocar um If.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso, então, eu colocando um if para cada letra, eu eliminaria o problema de mostrar os arquivos do desktop, que não estão dentro de uma pasta ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta uma função antes desta função que você colocou na sua resposta. Essa função anterior percorreria apenas as pastas do desktop. Aqui vai um exemplo, claro, falta ajustar às suas necessidades, mas basicamente seria:

```
public void SearchDesktopDirectories()
{
    var desktopDirectories = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));
//aqui já pode fazer a pesquisa pela letra que você quer consultar
    foreach(var desktopDirectory in desktopDirectories.GetDirectories(letra))
    {
        //aqui você percorre apenas as pastas do desktop, passando como parâmetro a letra de pesquisa, e com o retorno insere na sua Tree
        CreateDirectoryNode(desktopDirectory, letra);
    }
}

public void CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, string letra)
{
    //aqui dentro segue normal o seu método
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories(letra))
    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory, letra));

    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
    return directoryNode;
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde Gabriel. Gostaria de te perguntar. A função `SearchDesktopDirectories` teria um parâmetro string chamado letra ? e cada botão da tela inicial do programa, iria chamar essa função também?

Comment: Sim, pode ser incluído esse parâmetro letra. Como eu disse na resposta, você deve adaptar essa resposta às suas necessidades. Como você quer filtrar por letra as pastas, deve ter esse parâmetro letra no SearchDesktopDirectories.

Comment: Gabriel, gostaria de te agradecer pela ajuda. Fiz as modificações e consegui mostrar apenas as pastas do desktop. Muito obrigado !

Comment: @AgnerRibeiro que bom cara! Se foi de ajuda essa minha resposta, você poderia marcar como resposta da sua pergunta? Obrigado